# Jquery / Regex Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following input.

```
<input type="tel"  id="Phone maxlength="10"/>
```

I'm trying to use Jquery amd regex to validate the number's format.

The jquery / regex is as follows.

```
  $(function () {
    var reg = /(([2-9]{1})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4}))$/
    var Input = $("input#phone").val();
    if ($(z).val() == (reg)) {
    alert("Valid")
    }
  });
```

This is not working for me, does anyone see why? Or is there a better way to do this?]

Comment: Besides the correction that @falsetru pointed out, your regex itself is not the cleanest. You don't want to allow dashes? You can reduce it down to this without changing the meaning at all: `/[2-9]\d{9}$/`. Unless you are trying to use the groups created by all those parens.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method of regular expression object:

```
> /1/ == '1'
false
> /1/.test('1')
true
```

---

```
if (reg.test($(z).val())) {
    alert("Valid")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/Whb55/

**HTML:-**

```
<form>
    <input type="tel" id="Phone" maxlength="10" pattern="[2-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Great simple answer, not very customizable. Not fully cross browser compatable

Comment: This post could be helpfull to more customize this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038941/jquery-regex-validation

Answer (score 0):

Dude, Use Validate Plugin for Validation
 Example:

```
   $(".selector").validate({
     rules: {
    // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
    // compound rule
    /*Phone is the name of the input*/
phone: {
  required: true,
  minLength: 10,
  maxLength: 10
     }
},
  messages: {
phone: {
  required: "We need your Phone no to contact you",
  minLength: "Your email address must be 10 Characters",
  maxLength: "Your email address must be 10 Characters"
}
}
});
```

[Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Comment: I'm not able to for this project.