# Basic jQuery syntax problems while trying to validate user input - please advise

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, zipcode

I am new to coding as I am sure you will be able to tell from my question as I feel like this should be easy to accomplish, but I have struggled with this for longer than I care to admit and now must ask for guidance.

In the following code, I receive the alert "Not a Zip Code" with every input - whether it is a valid zip code or not.

```
$("body").on("click", "#searchBtn", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
// The below is a regular expression (regex) to ensure user enters either a 5 digit or 9 digit US zip code format
var zip = ("^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$;");  
var input = $("#userInput").val().trim();
if (input!=zip) {
    alert("Not a Zip Code");  //the end goal is to have the placeholder color turn red
} else {
    alert("Thank you - your entry is valid");  //the end goal is to have the placeholder say "You are searching in zip code " (+ zip)"
};
});
```

To piggy-back on this issue - when I replace: alert("Not a Zip Code");
With (and I've tried multiple formats at this point but one example is:

```
$("#userInput").addClass('red');
```

And for the above I added in my CSS the following:

```
.red::placeholder {
color: red;
}
```

I have also searched the similar questions on this board, but they are either more advanced than my current understanding or use programs I am not yet familiar with.
Thank you in advance for the assist!

Comment: I should add that I do have my above javaScript code wrapped in the jQuery document.ready function.

Comment: You need to change `if` condition, you should use it like `!input.match(zip)` instead of `input != zip`. i.e. we can't compare string with regex, instead use match() method to check against regex. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Comment: You need to change `zip` like `var zip = /^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/` and try to check not the equality use `.test()`, like `zip.test(input)`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038941/jquery-regex-validation/16240795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use JS's [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- Use jQuery's [`.toggleClass()` method](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
- Use this simpler RegExp for US ZIP postal codes: `^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$`

```js
$("body").on("click", "#searchBtn", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var $input = $("#userInput");
  var input = $input.val().trim();
  // Ensure user enters either a 5 digit or 9 digit US zip code format
  var isValid = /^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/.test(input);
  
  $input.toggleClass('is-invalid', !isValid);
  alert(isValid ? "Thank you - your entry is valid" : "Not a Zip Code");

});
```

```css
.is-invalid::placeholder { /* Don't use color-specific classes! */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter US ZIP code">
<button id="searchBtn">SEARCH</button>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great.  It is exactly what I needed.  And thank you for the advice on color-specific classes as well. And I can see that the code works as expected when I run the snippet. But for some reason when I paste this exact answer into html, css and js documents on my computer in vs code (blank docs - not existing code) - it does not generate an alert - nor when I apply it to my existing project - but I will try to figure that out...

Comment: Figured out my issue - the code was being held up by some things that were commented out.  This code was exactly what I needed.  Thanks again!